# Why does "read" have to be a system call run in "Kernel Mode"?

Tags: c, linux, file, unix, operating-system

As I understood, the UNIX function `read()` will cause an interrupt(TRAP) and invoke the system call `read`. I also remembered that it has to switch to "Kernel Mode" before invoking the system call `read` and the switching is expensive..

I was wondering that why the `read` operation has to be delegated to system call in "Kernel Mode", instead of being done in "User Mode" completely.

For example, if there could be a service in "User Mode" which manages the access permissions of files, the `read` operation can just request this service, not disturbing the Kernel..

And for the disk driver, it is said in this [link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/01/understanding-user-and-kernel-mode.html) that

> Device drivers can run in either user or kernel mode

Does anyone have ideas about this? Why does  `read` have to be in Kernel Mode?

Comment: Assuming a usermode service that handles access permissions, how does that service get the contents of files?

Comment: @Hasturkun It may use an internal function (ask the driver for data) to get the contents. This function is protected and can't be called by other processes directly.

Comment: And... how do you intend to protect that function? If all code is run in userspace mode, that means that ANY process can directly "talk" to the device, surpassing any "protected" function, compromising all the system.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix I understand what you mean. If you're right, it seems that the disk driver can't run in User Moder completely if "access permissions" are necessary..

Comment: It can run in usermode if you make the hardware registers associated with the disk drive accesible to an user process, but that comes with nasty consequences... if an user process can access the hardware registers of the hard disk, ANY user process can, so ANY process can traverse the filesystem and the access permission system for managing who can do what to a file becomes useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: it's no longer true that calling kernel is very expensive. It used to be when causing an exception/trap/fault/interrupt were the only way to switch from user mode to kernel mode in x86 systems, but that all changed with the addition of the `systenter`/`sysexit` machine code instructions, which perform a more lightweight transition.

Even if it is/were expensive, in terms of time consumed, system calls that deal with character and block device drivers should run in kernel mode because dealing with hardware devices involves reading and writting to hardware registers, which could be memory mapped or accessed thru I/O ports.

These registers must be protected from any access from userspace process. Not doing so may lead to any process to not to use the established API for reading a file, and directly use the hardware registers to read and write to the device. In the case of a disk with file, this would allow the userprocess to bypass the filesystem entirely, and hence, all the security and permission system.

So, if we need to protect these hardware registers so no user process can use them, code that does use them cannot run at the same priviledge level as any other user process. Hence, they run in another (more priviledged) mode, which is what is called "kernel mode".

Think on what would happen if you configure a Linux system so `/dev/sda` (usually the main harddisk in which the root filesystem lives) is read/write to anybody and everybody:

```
# chmod 666 /dev/sda
```

Having done this is more or less the equivalent of exposing the hard disk device to any user process. You can effectively write a program that could open, read, and write files stored within this device, but at the same time, you can write a program that open, read and write ANY files within the partition, no matter which permissions files have.

That said, there are cases in which a system runs only trusted applications. This kind of system doesn't need the level of protection that is present in a general purpose system, and hence it can benefit from the increased speed that comes by not depending on layers of APIs to isolate the process from the hardware. The most widely known example would be a videoconsole system. I recall that Windows CE used to run all its programs and device drivers at the same privilege too.

Answer (score 6):

Is not the way Operating Systems are designed. The definition of OS is to handle the computers' hardware and to bring resources to their users. Operating Sysmtes also have the concept of user mode and kernel mode (as you said).

By having these concepts, OS define an specific line to what a *user* might do and what not. Letting them manage hardware is definitely something OS don't want users to do.

`read` usually involves a hardware access. Accessing hardware is cumbersome and error prone and can leave the computer in an unusable state. Operating System uses drivers to control the computer's hardware.

Issuing a `read` (assuming a hard disk IO) generally makes a driver to send a set of commands to the disk controller, read it's output, pass it to main memory, etc. This are dangerous operations that shouldn't be trusted to User Mode.

If *there would be a service* in user mode to handle this. Context switch still would be needed to be done, because the service would be running as another process.

Sure thing it can be done an Operating System that allows this. But modern operating systems aren't design to fulfill this behavior.

There are other approaches to building operating systems that relies on **microkernels**. A microkernel just do the minimum to get the pc started and leave everything else to other modules. Meaning that if a module crashes, the system still up. That's the case of specific drivers, filesystems, etc. I don't know if microkernels let these run in user space though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But it is said that "Device drivers can run in either user or kernel mode" (see my link in the question).  Is it necessary for `read` to be run in Kernel Mode if the driver is in User Mode?

Comment: @Firegun very nice article. It talks about Windows though. The question is labeled as linux so I assumed it. I don't know about Windows. I'll add a bit more information about microkernels but very general. For me, __its just a design decision for safety__.

Comment: Even in Windows, *part* of the driver is running in Kernel mode (usually a generic framework 'stub'). It can't have access to hardware that's not somehow delegated by the kernel.

Comment: The closest example of such delegation is DRI in Linux/X. The kernel delegates writing to *specific* areas of address-space memory-mapped to your video card.

Comment: @Firegun: You'd still need a system call for kernel-mode device drivers. There wouldn't be much benefit in providing a separate non-kernel function for accessing user-mode device drivers -- especially since the user-mode code doesn't know, or care, whether the relevant device has a user-mode or kernel-mode driver.

Comment: By the way, there are many other subsystems that mimic file behavior, such as `/proc`, `/sys` and `/dev` files as well as many others. If you want `read` to only work in user space, you have to move every subsystem that `read` could refer to (which are many, since in Unix, _everything_ is a file) in user space. Perhaps a microkernel could pull this off, but the Linux kernel is not one.